# How to calc the proportional size of a image with Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, resize, image-scaling

I have the width and the false height of a image and want calc a new proportional with Javascript/jQuery.
Must use the width and calc the new height.

I hope anyone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, why not just use CSS and have the height set to `auto`?  Wouldn't that be better?  Than all you have to do is set the width!  You can also do `max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;`

Comment: Solom, that's right. But i must use javascript because the js libary i use scale it wrong and not works when im use max-height, or height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var newWidth = <whatever the new width is>;
var width = $('#imgID').width();
var proportion = newWidth/width;
var newHeight = <existing height> * proportion;
```

Comment: I have only one width, not a new width.

Comment: @user1878413 then use: var width = $('#imgID').width();
var proportion = <whatever the width value is>/width;
var newHeight = <existing height> * proportion;

Answer (score 1):

Im using css width:100% and using element.clientHeight to get its height.